# How can i scrape images from website

Tags: phantomjs

Hie I am trying to scrape images from website. I all seems easy when i try to scrape image with src attribute. But when using srcset throws an error undefined and doesnt work ???
I tried it by 
      var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onLoadFinished = function(){

```
var urls = page.evaluate(function(){
    var image_urls = new Array;
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(q = 0; q < images.length; q++){
        images[q].srcset = images[q].src;
        image_urls.push(images[q].src);
    }
    return image_urls;
});    

console.log(urls.length);
console.log(urls[0]);

phantom.exit();
}
page.open('https://www.example.com/Food/Pears/Anjou-Pears');
```

All i want to do is that i can input url and it extracts and downloads image from url.

Upadate: I also tried following code to get img url and got me that phantom js crashed i.e"PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at
http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html and file a bug report.
Segmentation fault: 11".

```
var url = "https://www.example.com/Food/Fruits/Pears/Anjou-Pears/p/20174514001_KG";
var page = require( 'webpage' ).create();

page.open(url, function( status ) {
if ( status === 'success' ) {
    page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js', function() {
        var link = page.evaluate(function() {
            if($( 'img' ).length != 0)
            {
                return $( 'img' ).attr('srcset');
            }

        });
        console.log( link );
        phantom.exit();
    });
} else {
    console.log( 'FAIL' );
}
});
```

Comment: What error do you see? Without the exact text of the error, no-one can really help you. Oh, and `images[q].srcset = images[q].src;` seems wrong.

Comment: Error Shows me Undefined and second log shows 0

Comment: Also, [this library may help you](https://github.com/sindresorhus/srcset) parsing `srcset`.

Comment: I tried but website i am scrapping from doesnt have array in srcset but just a image url any way how to code